# Apple XServe 2,1 Questions (ESXi, Temp)

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, vmware-esxi, mac-osx-server, vmware-vsphere

So I have Apple XServe 2, 1 (Earlier 2008 model)

I am trying to install ESXi 5.1 on it. I've read it that it's possible. I'be burnt the ESXi ISO to a dvd-r. I am now trying to boot from it but I have no luck on that. I've looked at: Startup Disk, and I dont see my cd listed there as bootable.

I've also tried the Power OFF, System ID approach but no luck on that either.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

1. My CPU's are running 45C - 50C, is that a safe temp to keep ?
2. I shutdown my XServe, however the fans are still running. Is that normal ? Is there a way to disable that ?

Sorry for "noob-ish" questions, I am just new to it all. The main purpose for this server is to be able to run multiple vms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XServe 2,1 is **not** on the [ESXi 5.1 HCL](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/hcl&ei=sCHpUPyCCImR0QGm_oCAAg&usg=AFQjCNEXuH3H1BNILfm7AMoBNO0jQXhT-g&sig2=2-ywHuKKNPlm94SrOfXDfg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ). The XServer 3,1 is as well as the Mac Pro 5,1, but considering all XServes are end of life, I really wouldn't recommend running ESXi on *any* Apple rackmount hardware.

Comment: http://74bit.com/gossip/2012/03/apple-xserve-running-vmware-esxi-5/ it says he was able to get it to work. The biggest problem I'm having is not being able to even boot into the cd.

Comment: He is installing 5.0.0 there, not 5.1. Also, there is absolutely no guarantee that anything that isn't on the HCL will work. Seriously, if it's not there, get hardware that is.

Comment: alright, i'll take your word for it. I'll just install 10.7.5 on it because it's currently running only 10.5x. Thank you for the help, would you happen to know about the other 2 questions ?

Comment: `My CPU's are running 45C - 50C, is that a safe temp to keep ?` - Yes. They're all spec'd to at least 90C. `I shutdown my XServe, however the fans are still running. Is that normal ? Is there a way to disable that ?` - If it's powered off, the fans should shut off as well. Are you sure you're not sleeping/hibernating it by accident?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I shut them off. For example, let's say the psu plug is not plugged in. As soon as i plug it in, the fan and light automatically starts running in a low speed. Then, when i click the power button, that's when the computer actually turns on.

Comment: Also, I'll mark your answer as the best.

Answer (score -3):

I installed ESXi 6 on my early 2008 Xserve. From a CD, brunt from the iso downloaded from vmware.com

Worked like a charm and the Xserve is on the HCL for Vmware. So no problems there. UNLESS - you have the Raid card. If you have the Apple RAID card in your Xserve server, AFAIK (still) ESXi will not see more than one drive.

For some reason the Apple RAID card is not on the HCL for vmware (still).
At least that has been my experience with this.

Comment: Serverfault is a community for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins, we try to build and use supported/supportable systems at all times - anything else is a hack and not appreciated here.